# Is it possible to do 3,000 backstab or riposte damage?

Tags: dark-souls-2

Is it possible to inflict 3,000 damage or above in dark souls 2 pvp or pve?
If so, under what conditions? Buffs, stats, weapon, rings.

Comment: I'm assuming this is because someone managed this against you?

Comment: Might be possible with the leo ring, ring of blades,  channeller's trident buff, a high scaling dex/str thrust weapon, and a weapon buff like crystal magic weapon or sunlight blade.

Comment: A +10 Dagger with Sunlight Blade, coupled with Ring of Blades +2, Channeler's Trident Buff along with max DEX and STR (plus naked target with as low defense as possible) could conceivably deal a hefty amount of damage, but 3k? Don't think that's possible.

The biggest amount of damage I ever saw on YouTube was somewhere around 1.8k

Comment: I hit 3.5k today

Comment: @user2656801 That would appear to be the answer to your question. "Yes it is, because you achieved it." Feel free to answer you own question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfotunately, I have not experienced it myself, but just to help you theorize:

In NG++ with a fire-buffed Greatsword + 10 ( 65 strength and 37 dex ) I'm able to deal about 2300 damage with a backstab. Keep in mind that:

- There might be a stronger ultra greatsword, wich will result in more damage
- The only damage ring I wear is ring of blades + 2
- I buffed it with pyromancy wich is not that strong after all
- It has no enchantments on it, you might be able to buff it with raw power or Mundane to get more damage out of it

That being said, I think I might be able to get to a decent 2.4k or maybe even 2.5k damage if buffed properly, after some studies on rings and enchaments.

Now, we all know clerics have some interesting stuff:

- Sacred Oath, adds 50 damage to self
- Sunlight blade

Also, there are those new buff items in the first dlc wich increase can increase your stats for a while.

Conclusion:

Yes, I think it could be possible. If your build is well made (right armor and rings, like Ring of Blades and Leo Ring), use buffs, and you have high strength to scale with the Greatsword, you might be able to reach 3k.

You obviously need to be high level.

Again, I'm sorry I dont have any proof, And since I'm runinng out of Soul Vessels I don't want to risk it, but I hope this helped you to theorize a little bit.

**UPDATE**
[image: Max damage i've done]

Original poster apperently made it, and reached 3.5k damage.
Since we dont have any other details about his build or anything, I'll post my experience instead.
First, I had to choose a target. If you kill someone with a backstab, the damage display isn't the actual damage done but his life (confirmed).
The only enemy suitable for my tests, that popped out in my mind was the Mad Warrior (good excuse to finally farm his set).
I'll just make a quick summary:

- Base damage: 2409
- Damage with flame weapon: 2667
- Damage with lighting resin: 2682
- Old Leo Ring: Useless in backstab (tested). And since I'm not able to parry anything, I gave up on testing the ring. If someone would like to test the Leo Ring I'd be interested to know the damage difference with and without.

STR: 58 
Since I'm level 241, I could have added a little more strength to my Greatsword S scaling, but whatever...
We can see that there is a big difference between a weapon with and without buffs.
Keep in mind that I have no faith or int at all, so lighting and pyromancy damage are greatly reduced.

**Conclusion**

After this experience, I would say that you can add more damage if:

- You can counter parry with Old Leo Ring
- You are a cleric with a lot of strength and a lot of faith, which will increase buff damage and lighting scaling on your weapon

Comment: Looks enough like an answer to me. Might not be tested, but looks testable and isn't just wild speculation.

Comment: Tonight I'm gonna get some soul vessel and ill try to hit at least 2.5k without any faith buffs.

Comment: Updated answer, did some tests

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the late response. 
I don't know if this counts but I used brightbug buff, with great magic weapon buff, using a malformed skull, or a curved dragon greatsword to hit 3,700 damage on a red phantom npc alonne captain in the iron keep. The brightbug is apprently a 20% dmg buff. Also I probably could use unleash magic spell to boost damage 20% further. I'll edit when I did more testing. Thanks for your answer ben, very good.

Answer (score -1):

I have done over 3000 damage and you should be on ng+. You don't need max damage to do it. Its been patched though. Also depends on your opponents defense.